# Spark Job Take too Much Time

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, streaming, hdfs

I have 1GB data in Kafka and I am running spark-streaming job which take the data from kafka and in that I put some Java cleansing code and then after I put into the hadoop, but in parsing or in cleansing it's taking too much time.
My Spark Standalone cluster configs are:- Two nodes 16 GB Ram and 4 core.

Sample code is given below:

```
private void processRDD(JavaPairDStream < String, String > messages) throws JSONException {
    //messages.print();
    JavaDStream < String > fields = messages.map(new Function < Tuple2 < String, String > , String > () {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2179983619724411716 L;
        /**
         * @throws JSONException 
         * 
         */
        public String call(Tuple2 < String, String > message) throws JSONException

        {
            CustomParser customParser = new CustomParser();
            String ParseData = customParser.parse(message._2.getBytes());
            //System.out.println("=====>>>>>>1");

            return ParseData;
        }
    });
    JavaDStream < String > msgLines = fields.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction < String, String > () {
        public Iterable < String > call(String x) {
            //return Lists.newArrayList(x.split("\n"));
            return Arrays.asList(x.split("\n"));

        }
    });
    msgLines.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("/tmp/", ".csv");
}
```

Comment: How much time is too much? Is this data all coming in a single Kafka message? Can you share details on what CustomParser.parse actually does? This is likely where most of the cpu time is going.

Comment: Hi , For 1gb its taking 1hour and yes this is coming from single kafka topic and in that around 1cr records are available and CustomParser is doing only cleansing like remove garbage values, make datetimeformat from epoc etc.